# How to sum a column with cells containing text?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a a column that contains data size values, with numbers and varying text. Some have values like "3.54 TB" and some like "620 GB". Ultimately I want to get the total data size of a given column. For example, 3.54 TB + 620 GB = 4.16 TB.

If I could send the sum of cells containing "TB" to one cell, sum the cells containing "GB" to another cell - divide this GB cell by 1000, I can easily add those two cells.

Are there any formulas to sum a column of cells containing text? I do not want to download a plug-in.

Someone asked this here: [How can I sum a column with cells containing text?](https://superuser.com/questions/993442/how-can-i-sum-a-column-with-cells-containing-text)

And salvo provided the formula below, but I return a "too few arguments" error when I use it...

```
=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1:A6000,SEARCH("p",A1:A6000)-1)))
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this that iterates the cells and test the ending converting it all to `TB` and adding them together:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A2,FIND(" ",A1:A2&" ")-1)/1000^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A2,2),{"TB","GB","MB","KB"},0)-1)) & " TB"
```

As it iterates `LEFT(A1:A2,FIND(" ",A1:A2&" ")-1)` returns the numeric part.

`MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A2,2),{"TB","GB","MB","KB"},0)-1` returns `0,1,2,3` depending on where the text part is found in the array `{"TB","GB","MB","KB"}`

`1000^` returns `1,1000,1000000,100000000000` depending on the return of the MATCH.

[image]

Comment: Nice use of array formulas, both for the input of sumproduct, and the lookup table for the units.

Comment: Great answer, what if there are blank cells? I cannot find a workaround if the range contains blank cells.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are probably other solutions to this, but this works:`=IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="TB",LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1))*1024^4,IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="GB",LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1))*1024^3))`
If you also have "MB" and "KB" in your column, you'll have to add appropriate IF statements to account for them. Once you've summed your column, you can divide by 1024^x to get back to the units you want, (i.e. 1024^4 for TB, 1024^3 for GB, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a simple formula for this. It requires a few steps:

1. Separate the numeric from the textual units
2. Convert the units into multipliers
3. Combine each number with its multiplier
4. Sum the results
5. Choose an appropriate unit to use

Numbers 2 and 5 are the tricky ones, since they require knowledge of the units. In my example below, I handle KB, MB, GB, and TB, and assume they mean base-10 multipliers (letting KiB, etc. mean base-2). But you may also want B, b, kb, KB, PB, EB, etc. and for every unit you want to handle, you need an extra IF() to turn it into a multiplier.

[image: Excel table with input values converted into bytes and summed, with formulas for each column shown on the right]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Write this formula in Cell C2 & fill down:**

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="TB",SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(RIGHT(A2,2),$A$2:$A$3)),VALUE(LEFT($A$2:$A$3,FIND(RIGHT(A2,2),$A$2:$A$3)-1)),0)),IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="GB",SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(RIGHT(A2,2),$A$2:$A$3)),VALUE(LEFT($A$2:$A$3,FIND(RIGHT(A2,2),$A$2:$A$3)-1)),0))/1024))
```

**N.B.** *I've divided the second part of the formula by 1024 to convert the GB into TB.*

**Write this formula in Cell C5:**

```
=ROUND(C2+C3,2)&" TB"
```

**Note,** *Adjust cell references in formula as needed.*