# How to sum a column with cells containing text (specifically "GiB") in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Someone previously asked how to get the sum of cells (containing " GB") and the following clever response was given: [How to sum a column with cells containing text?](https://superuser.com/questions/1336799/how-to-sum-a-column-with-cells-containing-text/1336820#1336820?newreg=f96bc9d9000e4af6be9d81ab7c4fe1ad)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A2,FIND(" ",A1:A2&" ")-1)/1000^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1:A2,2),{"TB","GB","MB","KB"},0)-1)) & " TB"
```

How can I modify this for GiB please?

I have tried changing "GB" to "GiB" (and "TB" to "TiB" etc) but it didn't work. Also wonder if I should change "/1000" to "/1024".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks @MarkusMeyer.  I have tried changing "GB" to "GiB" (and "TB" to "TiB" etc) but it didn't work.  Also wonder if I should change "/1000" to "/1024".

Comment: Did you change **2** to **3** in `RIGHT()` ? Otherwise, you are trying to find "iB" in an array where there is TiB, GiB, etc., but there is simply no iB.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSUN!  But do I need to change "/1000" to "/1024" as well?